# Element not found in the cache - Ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara

I see the below error when clicking on the button/enter text after moving to the next page in the same site:

> Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
>   [remote server] `resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454:in 'fxdriver.cache.getElementAt'`

Using the Capybara automation (Selenium web-driver), the browser automatically gets closed.

I have tried to put the session refresh statement before it closes.

```
visit current_url
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a pure Ruby question. Is it Ruby on Rails, for example? Perhaps add some tags?

Comment: Could you add some context - I've no idea what you're even trying to do

Comment: am using capybara automation through selenium webdriver

Comment: Please add your actual test code to the question so we can see what exactly you are doing - The "Element not found in the cache" error would tend to imply you're saving a reference to an element from one page and attempting to use it on the next.